# Importing Spring MVC Project Manually to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I have a little problem. I had googled for this problem and I haven't found any solution related.

My problem is, my office internet using proxy that banned me to download zip file. I need Spring MVC Project template in Spring Tool Suite (STS). So I downloaded the zip file at home assuming when I get to my office PC, I can install the zip to STS. But, I can't found the way.

Is it possible to install a zip project template to STS? If yes, how? Thanks before. (Sorry for my grammar)

Here is the download link of the template I want:
[Spring MVC web application development project](http://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/help/org.springframework.templates.mvc-3.2.2.zip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will extract zip file and go to inside folder in templete.zip is import succesully into eclipse IDE.i have tested.

Comment: I think this is the best I could get. But for 2 projects I need to copy the content in template.zip to 2 different folder. Thanks for the idea! :D

Answer (score 2):

Try to import your project in eclipse.
Follow below mentioned steps

Right Click--->Import--->Import-->search for Archive file

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the zip file is not a project. It is a project template. The zip contains template.xml, template.zip and wizard.json

Comment: To import a template in Eclipse

    Click Window > Preferences.
    Expand JAVA, expand Editor and click Templates.
    Click Import.
    Select the template file that you want to import.
    Click OK.
    The template list is updated to include the template that you imported.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried your steps but it said "Failed to read templates" in error log. Seems I need more lucks :P